# Meteor + React: Can't get data from mongoDB Collection

Tags: mongodb, reactjs, meteor, collections, meteor-1.4

I have a Meteor Application that I'm developing with React. I still have the `autopublish` package in my project (`autopublish@1.0.7`).

Here is my relevant code:

**MainMenu.jsx**

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react'
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor'
import { FlowRouter } from 'meteor/kadira:flow-router'
import { createContainer } from 'meteor/react-meteor-data'

import { ChatRooms } from '/imports/api/chatrooms.js'

export class MainMenu extends Component {
    render() {
        console.log(this.props.chatrooms)

        return (
            {/* Render stuff here is not part of the scope of this question */}
        )
    }
}

MainMenu.PropTypes = {
    chatrooms: PropTypes.array.isRequired
}

export default createContainer(() => {
    return {
        chatrooms: ChatRooms.find({}).fetch()
    }
}, MainMenu)
```

**chatrooms.js**

```
import { Mongo } from 'meteor/mongo'

export const ChatRooms = new Mongo.Collection('chatrooms')
```

The `console.log(this.props.chatrooms)` in the `MainMenu` Component always returns an empty array (`[]`).

There are definitely items in the `Mongo` Database because when I run the `meteor mongo` command in my console and type `db.chatrooms.find({});` it returns the 3 items that I've inserted to test this all.

Anyone have any idea what I may be doing wrong here? Help would be much appreciated!

Comment: your code snippet in the question helped me fetching data in my first meteor+react+mongo app that I was unable to achieve from the last 4+ hours, thanks :)

Comment: Glad this helped you out @adi! :)

Comment: I've observed a strange thing that my code doesn't work without this snippet in the first class:
        `componentDidMount() {
  Meteor.subscribe('projects');
 }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've figured it out. I left out a crucial step of this whole process.

In my `/server/main.js` file I needed to add the following line which fixed everything:

```
import '../imports/api/chatrooms.js
```